# How to get Result From Custom Join query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, join, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have 4 tables
Each of them has Entity class, DTO, and Repository

```
public interface Interface_A extends JpaRepository< Entity_A, Integer> {
      Entity_A findByName(String name);
}

public interface Interface_B extends JpaRepository< Entity_B, Integer> {
      Entity_B findByName(String name);
}
```

all of these functions are working properly functions in the JPA repository.
**BUT** when I try to join 2 tables it says
`Carn't create the bean`
please insert proper code to do this

```
    public interface Interface_C extends JpaRepository< Entity_A, Integer> {
      Entity_A findByName(String name);

      @Query(value = "SELECT a.name,b.name FROM Entity_A a INNER JOIN Entity_B b ON a.id = b.aid )
      List<Entity_A> getDataFromJoin(); // insert code here 
    }
```

Assume that

1. two tables have the same name as the entity
2. Entity_A --> (id,name)
3. Entity_B --> (id,name,aid)

Comment: Thats not how jpa repositories works. You must specify joins in your entities, so EntityA has a field with type EntityB, then when you use Repository<EntityA> to load it, all EntityA will have EntityB already fetched from db

Comment: Yes I know that in actual case I have 7 tables and a large query. So I just want to know " how to get custom output from database by only changing the repository layer " I insert new POJO class instead of Entity A but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, so you need to write your own query using @Query annotation on a method, see ie https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: I almost read that documentation. It has no explanation on JOIN

Comment: If you just specify that you want to use native query you just write the native sql, you can do anything you need, even use db specific functions

Comment: How to write a native SQL query for this task?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232333/discussion-between-nilupul-heshan-and-nadir).